# Deformed Solidify Modifier.(Even Thickness)

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, solidify-modifier

Ctrl + Alt + Q display shows the rear bumper of a vehicle from the Top view, Perspective view, Front view and side view.

The bumper has a Mirror modifier, Subdivision surface and a solidify Modifier.

In the Solidify Modifier, we can see that the Even Thickness option is toggled off.
[image]

By the time the Even Thickness is toggled on, there's an extension at the bottom.
[image]

I had thought that probably theres a vertex that had extended, but its not the case as I had tried to make a selection(click and drag) in that area, but no vertex seems to have been selected. The extension is just there, extended.

Is there an explanation for what I must have done wrong?

Comment: Possibly, the object has some scale?

Answer (score 0):

Edit Mode > Ctrl + A > M > By Distance